# Extends MatDialog in Angular 9 - Types have separate declarations of a private property '_attachDialogContainer'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

Code was working fine before I upgraded angular 8 to 9. Upgrade has added Injectable decorator before the class and now its giving an error. I have deleted the other functions which are written but are not causing the issue.

`Class 'CustomDialog' incorrectly extends base class 'MatDialog'.`

Types have separate declarations of a private property _attachDialogContainer.

Deleting Injectable gives runtime error that  _createInjector and _attachDialogContainer are both private functions in the parent class.

What is the possible solution to this situation.

```
**@Injectable()**
export class CustomDialog extends MatDialog {
  constructor(
    _overlay: Overlay,
    private injector: Injector,
    @Optional() _location: Location,
    @Optional() @Inject(CUSTOM_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS) _defaultOptions: CustomDialogConfig,
    @Inject(CUSTOM_DIALOG_SCROLL_STRATEGY) scrollStrategy: any,
    @Optional() @SkipSelf() _parentDialog: CustomDialog,
    overlayContainer: OverlayContainer
  ) {
    super(
      _overlay,
      injector,
      _location,
      _defaultOptions ? _defaultOptions : new CustomDialogConfig(),
      scrollStrategy,
      //@ts-ignore
      _parentDialog,
      overlayContainer
    );
  }

  private _createInjector<T>(
    config: CustomDialogConfig,
    dialogRef: MatDialogRef<T>,
    dialogContainer: MatDialogContainer
  ): PortalInjector {
   // some code
  }

  // /**
  //  * Attaches an CustomDialogContainer to a dialog's already-created overlay.
  //  * @param overlay Reference to the dialog's underlying overlay.
  //  * @param config The dialog configuration.
  //  * @returns A promise resolving to a ComponentRef for the attached container.
  //  */

  private _attachDialogContainer(
    overlay: OverlayRef,
    config: CustomDialogConfig
  ): CustomDialogContainer {
   // some code
  }
}
```

I am trying to extend the MatDialog class which was working fine with Angular 8 but with the update to Angular 9. After the Injectable decorator, code has started giving compile issues and there is no work around to it.

Comment: Can you not just rename `_attachDialogContainer` in your `CustomDialog `?

Comment: Are you using a correct version of material? After update of angular version you should update also your libraries

Comment: Not just _attachDialogContainer  it is also complaining about _createInjector function

Comment: Yes I am sure I have the correct version of Material